# How to create single global import file for references in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am looking for creating a global import file instead of importing the same libraries in each component (same import in each component).

I have seen index.ts file [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial#projectstructure) which includes the import references of file like component and service. but i am looking for a solution by which i can import following references in one file and then i must be able to import single file to my components instead of all the following references.

```
// Observable class extensions
export * from 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

// Observable operators
export * from 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
export * from 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
export * from 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

export { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
export * from 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Please help, i am new in angular 2 and could not find any help in this regard.

Comment: I'm affraid the barrel file (`export * from "some-lib"`) is the only way...

Comment: the only thing that I know (apart from `barrel`) is regarding the `rxjs` operators...you can create a file with all this `rxjs/add/` and then just import the file you created in your component and you'll be able to use all methods without import each of `rxjs` operator.

Comment: I have achieved the above thing by creating a new ts file with name 'xyz' and then import that file into my component. 

    import { Component, OnInit } from ../xyz

But what will be the impact, will it load all the export libraries mentioned in the file? or it will only call the mentioned file in import statement?

Comment: I don't know for sure but, as we are talking about script, I think it will load all the exports.

Comment: that means it will impact the performance of the app? if it is not necessary to have all the mentioned libraries and only need one of them.

Comment: I'm afraid so. But I'm not a specialist in angular loading modules and performance. Maybe you need to take a further research about this or do yourself a performance test with your app using the solution you want and using the "regular way" to build an app. and see the difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224905/impact-of-global-import-file-in-angular-2/43224962#43224962

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the above thing by creating a new ts file with name `'xyz'` and then import that file into my component. the 'xyz' contains all the references.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from './xyz'
```

but after R&D, i got to know that this is not the best practice. details are in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224905/impact-of-global-import-file-in-angular-2) link.