# impact of global import file in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a file name `service.imports.ts` having following code.

```
export { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'
export { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
export { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export * from 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
export * from 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

and call that file in my angular 2 service.ts file by

`import { Http } from '../service.imports'`

As you can see i am only calling `Http` module and ignoring `Response, Headers, RequestOptions`.

how angular 2 handles this situation? will it load all the modules mentioned in `service.imports.ts` or it only loads the modules which are being called where that `service.imports.ts` is used i.e only `Http`?

I have the performance concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these imports don't matter. The compilation step will get rid of them.

It would be different if you'd add them to

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [...]
})
```

Using barrels was even an Angular style guide suggestion a while ago, until they discovered it regularly causes issues like [Angular 2 DI Error - EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters/38000323#38000323)

Comment: so do you suggest me to design my app in this way? Is it a good practice?

Comment: The Angular team moved away from it because it causes problems. I wouldn't create a file that collects all imports. I'd do it to some degree, like for modules (same granularity as `NgModule`), but not for a whole application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.